# ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.100: Installing opencv-contrib-python package on ARM CPU (Stratodesk OS)

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install opencv package on Raspberry Pi (Stratodesk OS). the best shot I got so far is through: https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple

However, after installing

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple
```

when importing the cv2 in python I get import error message related to **libhdf5_serial.so.100**:

> root@PNAR55:~# python3
>   Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
>   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> import cv2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 3,
>   in 
>   from .cv2 import *
>   ImportError: libhdf5_serial.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

besides, I tried to install opencv-python but without success

```
pip install opencv-python --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple
```

when importing cv2, I am getting a different ImportError message related to  **liblapack.so.3**

> import cv2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):    File "", line
>   1, in    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 3, in
>   
>       from .cv2 import * ImportError: liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

for your information, Stratodesk OS is quite different that Raspbian. I do not have git, cmake, apt-get commands.

if there is a way to overcome the error messages I am getting

Comment: Im stuck here too. I am trying to remove the new libhdf5_serial.so I think its 103 and install the old one libhdf5_serial.so.100 I think that should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to an incompatibility between your board and the OpenCV version. If you installed it via `pip` try `pip uninstall opencv-python` or `pip3 uninstall opencv-python` (depending of the python version you need (`pip` for `python2` and `pip` for `python3`). After uninstaling is complete, try to search for an older version of opencv and install via `pip3 install opencv-python==3.4.6.27` (this is the version that worked for me. I'm almost sure you'll need another one). Also, check this [link](https://github.com/amymcgovern/pyparrot/issues/34), and [this one](https://blog.piwheels.org/new-opencv-builds-including-opencv-4-x/)!